# Installing latest version of GCC from source

Tags: c++, c, gcc

i want to install latest version of GCC on RHEL 6.5 version.There is  a old version of GCC already installed(GCC version 4.4.7 20120313).I want a way such that i need to install GCC in my private folder and only i can use this to compile code.other users who compile should be based on older version.

Comment: Give a different installation path

Comment: Set `--prefix=$HOME/gcc` (or similar) when configuring the build

Comment: Or just install gcc-6.2 from [devtoolset-6](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-6/). You can enable the SCL when you want to use the new version.

Comment: what about the dependencies?

Comment: Dependencies should be listed under "prerequisites" in the instructions: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/